# gofabric8> Unable to unzip /Users/apple/.fabric8/bin/oc.zip zip: not a valid zip

Tags: maven, openshift, kubernetes, microservices, fabric8

I'm trying to set up environment for microservices. I'm using fabric8 to do that.

I'm using `mvn fabric8:cluster-start -Dfabric8.cluster.kind=openshift` command. while executing i'm getting following error...

```
  [INFO] gofabric8> Downloading https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v1.3.1/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.3.1-dad658de7465ba8a234a4fb40b5b446a45a4cee1-mac.zip...
    [INFO] gofabric8> **Unable to unzip /Users/apple/.fabric8/bin/oc.zip zip: not a valid zip fileUnable to download client zip: not a valid zip file**
    [INFO] gofabric8> using the executable /Users/apple/.fabric8/bin/minishift
    [INFO] gofabric8> running: /Users/apple/.fabric8/bin/minishift start --vm-driver=xhyve --memory=4096 --cpus=1
    [INFO] gofabric8> Starting local OpenShift cluster...
    [INFO] gofabric8> Downloading ISO
    [INFO] gofabric8> 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 18:50 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-14T16:05:32+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/224M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.1.49:cluster-start (default-cli) on project demo: Failed to execute gofabric8 start --batch --minishift --console. java.io.IOException: Failed to execute process stdin for gofabric8 start --batch --minishift --console: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ''' -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.1.49:cluster-start (default-cli) on project demo: Failed to execute gofabric8 start --batch --minishift --console. java.io.IOException: Failed to execute process stdin for gofabric8 start --batch --minishift --console: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '''
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem today when I attempted to follow the fabric8 get started instructions here: https://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gofabric8.html.
I used:
`gofabric8 start --minishift` and received this error:

`DSKTP-000003:~ usr$ gofabric8 start --minishift
fabric8 recommends OSX users use the xhyve driver
xhyve driver already installed
Downloading https://github.com/jimmidyson/minishift/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta.1/minishift-darwin-amd64...
Downloaded /Users/brent.fisher/.fabric8/bin/minishift
kubectl is already available on your PATH
Downloading https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v1.3.1/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.3.1-dad658de7465ba8a234a4fb40b5b446a45a4cee1-mac.zip...
Unable to unzip /Users/brent.fisher/.fabric8/bin/oc.zip zip: not a valid zip fileUnable to download client zip: not a valid zip file
using the executable /Users/brent.fisher/.fabric8/bin/minishift
Unable to get status fork/exec /Users/brent.fisher/.fabric8/bin/minishift: exec format errorDSKTP-000003:~ usr$`

I am using gofabric8 version 0.4.112:

`gofabric8 version
gofabric8, version 0.4.112 (branch: 'master', revision: '50d5d75')
  build date:       '20161129-10:39:49'
  go version:       '1.7.1'`

It seems that the minishift option tries to download a version of openshift client (oc) that no longer exists [1.3.1] at that url.  I was able to get around the error by manually downloading open shift from here: https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/tag/v1.3.2
and extracting it and renaming the extracted executable to `oc`.

Comment: I should note, I had to also load minishift from here: https://github.com/minishift/minishift/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta.1/minishift-1.0.0-beta.1-darwin-amd64.tgz

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what the output of this command is:

> gofabric8 version

The binary is in ~/.fabric8/bin if its not on your $PATH.

I wonder if its just that your gofabric8 binary is old. e.g. we have a 0.4.105 version now.

If your gofabric8 binary is old; its sounding like the auto upgrading isn't working correctly; so try deleting ~/.fabric8/bin/gofabric8 and re-running your mvn command

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases for the list of currently avalable releases.

Your maven build is looking for an older release:
https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v1.3.1/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.3.1-dad658de7465ba8a234a4fb40b5b446a45a4cee1-mac.zip

You can try to override the dependency in your builds pom and use the currently available version:
openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.3.2-ac1d579-mac.zip

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same thing and Brent's answer above worked for me. Oc is up to 1.3.3 now and minishift is up to Beta2.

To answer James' question, here's my fabric8 version:

gofabric8, version 0.4.113 (branch: 'master', revision: '0610f51')
  build date:       '20170110-20:02:39'
  go version:       '1.7.1'