# Having trouble getting Fabric8 set up on Mac OS

Tags: macos, openshift, kubernetes, fabric8

I'm trying to follow the getting started instructions over here:

http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gofabric8.html

I initially ran into a problem with it not being able to download and run oc and minishift but fixed that with help of this question:

[gofabric8> Unable to unzip /Users/apple/.fabric8/bin/oc.zip zip: not a valid zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586946/gofabric8-unable-to-unzip-users-apple-fabric8-bin-oc-zip-zip-not-a-valid-zip/41770951#41770951)

Now I'm running into it having problems setting up security and just hanging:

```
DeploymentConfigs all started so we can deploy fabric8


Deploying fabric8 to your OpenShift installation at https://192.168.64.2:8443 for domain 192.168.64.2.xip.io in namespace default

Loading fabric8 releases from maven repository:https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
Creating new Project: default
Deploying package: platform version: 2.4.19

SecurityContextConstraints restricted.........................................✘ User "admin" cannot create securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope
Cannot create SecurityContextConstraints: User "admin" cannot create securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope
Failed to create SecurityContextConstraints {{ } {fabric8      0 {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC} <nil> <nil> map[] map[] [] []} 0xc420604360 true [] [] [] [*] true true false false {RunAsAny <nil>} {RunAsAny <nil> <nil> <nil>} { []} { []} false [] [system:serviceaccount:openshift-infra:build-controller system:serviceaccount:default:default system:serviceaccount:default:fabric8 system:serviceaccount:default:gerrit system:serviceaccount:default:jenkins system:serviceaccount:default:router system:serviceaccount:default:registry system:serviceaccount:default:gogs system:serviceaccount:default:fluentd] [system:cluster-admins system:nodes]} in namespace default: User "admin" cannot create securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope
SecurityContextConstraints fabric8............................................✘ User "admin" cannot create securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope
Cannot create SecurityContextConstraints: User "admin" cannot create securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope
Failed to create SecurityContextConstraints {{ } {fabric8-sa-group      0 {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC} <nil> <nil> map[] map[] [] []} <nil> false [] [] [] [gitRepo configMap secret emptyDir] false false false false {RunAsAny <nil>} {RunAsAny <nil> <nil> <nil>} { []} { []} false [] [] [system:serviceaccounts]} in namespace default: User "admin" cannot create securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope
SecurityContextConstraints fabric8-sa-group...................................✘ User "admin" cannot create securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope
addClusterRoleToUser cluster-admin system:serviceaccount:default:fabric8......✘ User "admin" cannot get clusterpolicybindings at the cluster scope
addClusterRoleToUser cluster-admin system:serviceaccount:default:jenkins......✘ User "admin" cannot get clusterpolicybindings at the cluster scope
addClusterRoleToUser cluster-admin system:serviceaccount:default:configmapcontroller✘ User "admin" cannot get clusterpolicybindings at the cluster scope
addClusterRoleToUser cluster-admin system:serviceaccount:default:exposecontroller✘ User "admin" cannot get clusterpolicybindings at the cluster scope
addClusterRoleToUser cluster-reader system:serviceaccount:default:metrics.....✘ User "admin" cannot get clusterpolicybindings at the cluster scope
addClusterRoleToUser cluster-reader system:serviceaccount:default:fluentd.....✘ User "admin" cannot get clusterpolicybindings at the cluster scope
addClusterRoleToGroup cluster-reader system:serviceaccounts...................✘ User "admin" cannot get clusterpolicybindings at the cluster scope
addServiceAccount fluentd.....................................................✘ User "admin" cannot create serviceaccounts in project "default"
addServiceAccount registry....................................................✘ User "admin" cannot create serviceaccounts in project "default"
addServiceAccount router......................................................✘ User "admin" cannot create serviceaccounts in project "default"
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The username "admin" seem to have changed to "system:admin". I ran the installation completely manually:

```
minishift start
oc login -u system:admin
oc project default
gofabric8 deploy -y
```